# Github API for downloading a specific directory as tarball

Tags: git, github, deployment, tar

## My Problem

I have a huge git monorepo, from which I deploy a service from a small directory called `services`. I currently download the entire repo as tarball just for fetching that small directory, which is wasteful.

## What Have I Tried

- Cloning the repo and `git fetch` the changes - takes too much space on the target machine
- Getting the entire repo as tarball - wasteful in terms of time, as the tarball download can take up to 30 seconds, and I do need only a few small files from the entire tarball

## My Question

**How do I download a specific file or directory at a specific commit hash of a github repo as tarball?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout or clone single folders like in [this guide](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-can-I-download-a-specific-folder-from-a-GitHub-repo/m-p/88#M20) over at the GitHub community. They call this a sparse checkout, you first create the local repository like this:

```
mkdir directoryName
cd directoryName
git init
git remote add origin -f URL
```

And then you add the folder you want to use locally to `.git/info/sparse-checkout`. When executing a pull command after this git will only pull the folders mentioned in this file.

After this you can just fetch on a regular basis and it will only update this specific folder.

This is [the documentation on sparse checkouts](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout).